# Login to sql sever 2012 with sql authentication failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, authentication

I'm beginner in SQL Server, I need to make a login for my SQL Server.

I'd did this steps:

- In security folder right-click on logins folder and click on new login
- choose SQL SERVER AUTHENTICATION radio button and fill the textBox and unchecked Enforce password policy
- In user mapping page checked master data base and in data base roll membership checked db_owner and click ok
- right-click on server name and choose properties
- In security page choose SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode and click ok
- restart SQL Server

but when I tried to login by the user it failed. Am I wrong anywhere?
My SQL error logs:

> 2014-06-14 16:45:19.87 Logon       Login failed for user 'NT SERVICE\ReportServer'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'ReportServer'. [CLIENT: ]

Comment: What does your connection string look like?

Answer (score 0):

You should have checked the database you want to login to (in this case, probably ReportServer).

You do not need to restart sql server after creating a new login.

as a rule, **DO NOT** grant db_owner on Master database to any login. this database is too important to expose to user logins. by default, it should not be tempered with by anyone that is not sa.

Also, the error message suggests that you tried to login using windows authentication, unless you sql user name is 'NT Services\ReportServer'

Please show your connectionString (of course, delete the server ip and user password)